# How to get the value of a boolean propery of a class Action<T = any>?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this class:

```
  export class Action<T = any> {
      title: string = '';
      action!: (e: T) => void;
      icon?: string = '';
      classes? = 'w-acoes';
      **hide?: (e: T) => boolean;**
 }
```

And in my GridConfig I use it like this to hide the option when the business logic demands:

```
 this.config = {
            fields,
            actions: [
                {
                    title: 'Add',
                    action: (e) => this.service.add(e),
                    hide: (e) => {
                        return !this.check(e)
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Remove',
                    action: (e) => this.service.remove(e),
                    hide: (e) => {
                        return !this.check(e)
                    }
                }
            ]
        } as GridConfig<MyEntity>;
```

...

```
check = (e) => e.prop;
```

The problem is that when both of the actions go hid the options button still appears and the mat-menu is mounted empty, just a box without nothing to click on. I would like to hide the option when everything is hidden.

```
<button 
        mat-icon-button 
        *ngIf="allOptionsHidden()" 
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="actionsMenu" 
        [matMenuTriggerData]="{item: item, config: config}">
             <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>

<mat-menu #actionsMenu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-item="item">
        <div *ngFor="let action of config.actions">
            <div *ngIf="!hide(item, action)">
                <button mat-menu-item (click)="action.action(item)">
                    <span>{{action.title}} </span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

...

```
allOptionsHidden() {
        return this.config.actions.every(x => x.hide.valueOf() === true)) ? true : false;
    }
```

[image: This image shows an empty menu box]

This is the empty menu box that opens. I would like to hide the three dots button when all menu options are hidden.

Comment: You have a *class* `Action` but your actions appear to be plain Javascript objects? Did you maybe mean to use an *interface*?

Comment: I did not mean to use an interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have your *ngIf wrong.

Based on your function:

```
allOptionsHidden() {
    return this.config.actions.every(x => x.hide.valueOf() === true)) ? true : false;
}
```

You are checking if all elements should be hidden. This will return **true** in the case you describe and will verify the *ngIf condition on the button.

You should use the logical not in the condition on your button like this in order to hide it since you only want to show if the function returns **false**:

```
*ngIf="!allOptionsHidden()"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, you were right about it, but... valueOf was undefined somehow, so, I'm still stuck.

If I only could find a way of checking the value of the function...

Comment: Have you tried x.hide() instead of x.hide.valueOf() ?